# Bug when using minified external OpenLayers and webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, openlayers

I am building a module for OpenLayers using Webpack 3.

OpenLayers is not bundled itself with the module and is imported separately in the HTML file.

The external `ol.js` being minified, my minified module attempts to call functions with their full name, e.g :

```js
t.getOverlayContainerStopEvent()).appendChild(this.element);
```

This inevitably yields `t.getOverlayContainerStopEvent is not a function` as the function is currently uglified as `t.XXyy ; indeed, this function is **not part of the API** and is not meant to be overriden.

Now this code only works if using **OpenLayers 5.X** (as it retains function names) or **previous versions in debug mode** (ol-debug.js).

I assume this is normal as OL5 now uses full function names ; how can I  make this work with previous OpenLayers versions ? I know that this is possible as I browsed through a few libraries doing the same, sadly none of these were using Webpack.

Comment: "the function is currently uglified as t.XXyy" Have you enabled extremely aggressive uglification for `ol.js`? Normally it would avoid renaming things that are publicly accessible like that.

Comment: ol.js is minified by default, I did not recompile the library with different build settings and would like to avoid doing so !

Comment: If `ol.js` has been minified to `t.XXyy` then that seems like the mistake. Your application's `t.getOverlayContainerStopEvent()` has no way to know that it has been renamed to `t.XXyy`.

Comment: The reason this function is uglified is because it is not part of OpenLayers's API (and thus is not meant to be extended). However I believe there has to be a way to call this uglified method even from a compiled ES6 module !

Comment: You can of course call it as long as it's publicly exposed, but you'd need to use the uglified name in your own code. There's no way to go from the original name to an uglified name.

Comment: Using the uglified name will prevent my code from working with OL 5.X.
Do you have any idea how the [ol-ext](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/) and [geoportal-extensions](https://github.com/IGNF/geoportal-extensions) libraries work, on top of any version of OpenLayers ? They use ES6 modules as well, but not webpack. I'm thinking this might be related to the way they do inheritance, i.e using `ol.inherits()` instead of extending the Control class.

It might not be related to webpack...